Gauss sums over number field, residue a prime ideal
Let $\omega$ be a nonzero element of the number field $K$ and write $\mathfrak{a}$ for its denominator.
Hecke defined Gauss sums by
$$C(\omega) = \sum_{x \text{ mod } \mathfrak{a}} \exp(\mathrm{tr}(x^2 \omega)).$$
(here $x \text{ mod } \mathfrak{a}$ means that $x$ is an element of $\mathfrak{o}_K / \mathfrak{a}$, where $\mathfrak{o}_K$ is the ring of integers of $K$). I wanted to know the exact values of the above sum for prime ideals. There are some results for $C(\omega)$ but they do not provide any explicit expression for the same.
Is there any literature where they provided the values of $C(\omega)$ where $\mathfrak{a}$ is a prime ideal of $\mathfrak{o}_K$?

See http://hboylan.de/static/documents/hat.pdf  by Boylan and Skoruppa.

@FranzLemmermeyer, this is just for the case when the field is a quadratic field, I am seeking for the general number field
